# What are possible ways of assigning an array's first and last item as well as the array of items in between each to a separate variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-assignment

let's say I have the following data array

```
["New York", "Madrid", "Roma"]
```

And I have 2 other variables and another array

```
firstValue = '';
middlesValues = []
lastValue = ''
```

output

```
firstValue = 'New York'
middlesValues = ['Madrid']
lastValue = 'Roma'
```

And I would like for example to put the first value in the array each time in a variable, the middle values in an array and the last value in the last variable.
And if I have only two values in the array, to put only the first value and the last one in the 2 variables.

How can I proceed.

Comment: Regarding all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use array.slice to get the subarray, returns an empty array if you only have 2 elements.

```js
const array= ["New York", "Madrid", "Roma"];

const firstValue = array[0];
const middlesValues = array.slice(1, array.length - 1);
const lastValue = array[array.length - 1];

console.log(firstValue);
console.log(middlesValues);
console.log(lastValue);
```

Comment: `Array.splice` is destructive and will remove elements from the original array. However, `Array.slice` will achieve the same result but not remove anything.

Comment: @GenericUser you are right, I updated the answer

Comment: There is no need to do a lookup for an array's `length` since [`slice` also accept negative values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#parameters). And meanwhile almost all modern browsers support the possibility of accessing single items via [`at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to get the first element, [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to get the last, and the rest would be the middle ones:

```js
const partition = (arr = []) => {
  const array = [...arr];

  const firstValue = array.shift();
  const lastValue = array.pop();
  const middlesValues = array;

  return { firstValue, middlesValues, lastValue};
}

console.log( partition(["New York", "Madrid", "Boston", "Roma"]) );
console.log( partition(["New York", "Madrid", "Roma"]) );
console.log( partition(["New York", "Madrid"]) );
console.log( partition(["New York"]) );
console.log( partition([]) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach depends on whether the OP wants the original data to be mutated or not.

The shortest non mutating way is to use a combination of [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) and [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) ...

```
let [firstValue, ...middlesValues] = array;
let lastValue = middlesValues.pop();
```

possible approaches could be ...

```js
// - approach does not mutate the original data.
// - it does so by using array destructuring and `pop`.
let sampleData = ["New York", "Madrid", "Roma", "Paris"];

let [firstValue, ...middlesValues] = sampleData;
let lastValue = middlesValues.pop();

console.log({ firstValue, lastValue, middlesValues, sampleData });

sampleData = ["New York", "Madrid"];

[firstValue, ...middlesValues] = sampleData;
lastValue = middlesValues.pop();

console.log({ firstValue, lastValue, middlesValues, sampleData });
console.log('\n');


// - approach does not mutate the original data.
// - it does so by uitlizing `at` and `slice`.
sampleData = ["New York", "Madrid", "Roma", "Paris"];

firstValue = sampleData.at(0);
lastValue = sampleData.at(-1);
middlesValues = sampleData.slice(1, -1);

console.log({ firstValue, lastValue, middlesValues, sampleData });

sampleData = ["New York", "Madrid"];

firstValue = sampleData.at(0);
lastValue = sampleData.at(-1);
middlesValues = sampleData.slice(1, -1);

console.log({ firstValue, lastValue, middlesValues, sampleData });
console.log('\n');


// - approach does mutate the original data.
// - it does so by by choosing the proven way of `shift` and `pop`.
sampleData = ["New York", "Madrid", "Roma", "Paris"];

firstValue = sampleData.shift();
lastValue = sampleData.pop();
middlesValues = sampleData;

console.log({ firstValue, lastValue, middlesValues, sampleData });
console.log(
  '(middlesValues === sampleData) ?..',
  (middlesValues === sampleData)
);
sampleData = ["New York", "Madrid"];

firstValue = sampleData.shift();
lastValue = sampleData.pop();
middlesValues = sampleData;

console.log({ firstValue, lastValue, middlesValues, sampleData });
console.log(
  '(middlesValues === sampleData) ?..',
  (middlesValues === sampleData)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```